# Customise the response on verification failure for a jwt Strategy NestJs

Tags: authentication, jwt, nestjs, passport-jwt

I successfully implemented a jwt strategy for authentication using nestJs.

Below is the code for the jwt strategy

```js
import { ServerResponse } from './../helpers/serverResponse.helper';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt, Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';
import { config as env } from 'dotenv';
import { Bugsnag } from '../helpers/bugsnag.helper';

env();

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'jwt') {
    constructor(
    private readonly logger: Bugsnag,
    ) {
    super({
        jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
        secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY,
        passReqToCallback: true,
    });

    }

    async validate(payload, done: Function) {
    try {
        const validClaims = await this.authService.verifyTokenClaims(payload);

        if (!validClaims)
            return done(new UnauthorizedException('invalid token claims'), false);
        done(null, payload);
    } catch (err) {
        this.logger.notify(err);
        return ServerResponse.throwError({
        success: false,
        status: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        message: 'JwtStrategy class, validate function',
        errors: [err],
        });
    }
    }
}
```

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55820591/nestjs-jwt-authentication-returns-401) that the validate function will be called only when a valid token was provided in the request headers and I'm okay with that. However, I would like to know if it is possible to customize the response object which is sent in that case (*invalid token provided*).

If yes, how do I do that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [exception filter](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1) to catch `UnauthorizedException`s and modify the response there if you'd like. The other option would be extending the `AuthGuard('jwt')` mixin class and adding in some logic around a `try/catch` for the `super.canActivate(context)`, then in the error read what the reason is and throw a specific `UnauthorizedException` with your custom message

Comment: Thank you @jay McDoniel.
Exception filters solved the problem quite nicely

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `AuthGuard('jwt')`'s `handleRequest` method to throw any exception on JWT Validation failure.

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  handleRequest(err: any, user: any, info: any, context: any, status: any) {
    if (info instanceof JsonWebTokenError) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid Token!');
    }

    return super.handleRequest(err, user, info, context, status);
  }
}
```

`JsonWebTokenError` comes from `jsonwebtoken` library, which is used internally by passport.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of how I return the error information back to the endpoint point is pretty much the same as the first answer. The difference is I wrap the error message from either `err` info`into an`UnauthorizedException`. The return values to the endpoint will be as follows.

```js
... import dependencies

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  ...
  handleRequest(err, user, info) {
    if (!user) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException(err || info);
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

[image]

Another thing that needs to be mentioned is that the error will only be thrown in the backend when you throw the `err` or `info` directly instead of wrapping them in the `Exception`. The return value to the endpoint will be `500 internal error` which is obviously not friendly

```js
... import dependencies

@Injectable()
export class JwtAuthGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
  ...
  handleRequest(err, user, info) {
    if (!user) {
      throw err || info;
    }
    return user;
  }
}
```

[image]